# F# type to combine 1D and 2D array

Tags: f#

Can I have a class with one member either be float array or array of float array like

```
type testArr(data: float[],...) =
  member x.data = data
  member x.others = ...
  new( data: float[][],...) = ???
```

I tried to define 
`type Value = Value1D of float[] | Value2D of float[][],` then define  `type testArr(data: Value,... )`, but I then need to rewrite a lot of code for `type Value` to repeat the `array` type methods like `.Item` etc. Alternatively, How do I define `type Value` inherited from `'a[]` but limit the elment type `'a` to be `float` or `float[]` only?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't always have a `float[][]` and just use `Value2D[0]` for the 1D scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why would you need this, but you can define a `TestArr` class with private constructor and add two static methods to create the two types (`float[]` and `float[][]`) that you want to allow:

```
type TestArr<'T> private(data:'T[]) = 
  member x.Data = data 
  member x.Others = 42
  static member Array1D(data:float[]) = TestArr(data)
  static member Array2D(data:float[][]) = TestArr(data)
```

Using an array of arrays always, but with just a single element for the 1D scenario as suggested by Gabe in a comment sounds like a good and simpler alternative.

Comment: I tested above with `let x = [|1.0;2.0|];;
let y = new TestArr<float>(x);;`, and got error ` Method or object constructor 'TestArr`1' not found`. what did I do wrong? thanks.

Comment: Tomas solution suggested private constructor, hence you cannot do new TestArr... instead you need to use Array1D method as par your sample case of 1D array. Also make sure these 2 methods(Array1D and Array2D) are static which seems be missing from Tomas code.

Comment: @Ankur - Thanks for the correction - yes, the last two methods should be static and the object can be created using `TestArr.Array1D(x)` or `TestArr.Array2D(y)` (the method names could be the same - e.g. `Create` - and you could use overloading too).